# How can I get the first and last word using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I know with regex you can get every word and their first letter with:

```
/\b(\w)/g,
```

But is there also a way to get the first word?(I tried a lot of googling but couldnt find any that did both instead of either first or last word)
I believe it should be possible to get both in 1 regex instead of 2 different ones.

A example for my string and wanted result?

String: Hello Mister world

Would give back: ['H', 'w']

Comment: Do you mean first and last word or first letter of first and last words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\w|\b\w(?=\S+$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/31

Edit:

```
^\s*(\w)|\b(\w)(?=\S+$)
```

Use this and grab the group or capture if there are spaces at start.

Comment: What if the input is `<space>Hello Mister d:world` ?

Comment: Avinash is right, also gives me this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ^

on this call:

elementText.match(^\w|\b\w(?=\S+$));

Comment: use this https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/33 regex. And get the characters you want from the captures..

Comment: @PrivateerGerrit use delimiters.`/^\s*(\w)|\b(\w)(?=\S+$)/`

Comment: @Avinash Raj 
It's not quite correct, this is myresponse:
`["H", "H", undefined, index: 0, input: "Hello mister world"]`

Comment: @PrivateerGerrit create an empty list and then push the captures (index 1 and index 2) into that list. Finally print it.

Answer (score 0):

While it will only handle fairly specific inputs, you should be able to use something like:

```js
var test = [
  "Get the first and last word",
  "Hello world!",
  "foo bar",
  "this is a test, for matches",
  "test"
];

var rex = /^((\w*)\s?).*?(\s?(\w*)[^\w\s]*)$/;

test.forEach(function(it) {
  document.getElementById("results").textContent += JSON.stringify(rex.exec(it)) + "\n";
});
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Matches 2 and 4 will give you the trimmed versions of the first and last words.

Broken down, the regex `/^((\w*)\s?).*?(\s?(\w*)[^\w\s]*)$/`:

1. Match the first sequence of word characters, optionally followed by whitespace (match 1 is the full sequence, match 2 excludes the trailing whitespace character).
2. Match some of anything, but leave room for the final word match.
3. Match another optional whitespace character, then some word characters, then anything else (presumably punctuation) (match 3 is the full sequence, match 4 excludes the leading whitespace and trailing punctuation)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\w).*\b(\w).*?$
```

will give you what you're looking for. [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pI3aZ7/1)

Comment: I'm getting the first word as a response. I need a javascript regex, not php

Comment: In this instance, the syntax is identical. You just need to use the captures `$1` and `$2`.